# How to create multiple forms in one/single page in Django?

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

I want to have 2 different forms in my page. But when I try save value of forms, they are saved only in form_fridge. I think, it exists, because I use one csrf_token for 2 forms. Can you help me?

```html
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id = "formTv">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form_tv.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id = "formFridge">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form_fridge.as_p }}
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
```

views.py

```py
def add_new(request):
    form_fridge = FridgeForm(request.POST, request.FILES, use_required_attribute=False)
    form_tv = TvForm(request.POST, request.FILES, use_required_attribute=False)
    if form_fridge.is_valid() and request.method == 'POST':
        form_fridge.save()
        return redirect('new')
    elif form_tv.is_valid() and request.method == 'POST':
        form_tv.save()
        return redirect('new')
    return render(request, 'appliances/add_new.html', {'form_tv': form_tv,
                                                       'form_fridge': form_fridge})
```

Comment: Check out `Inline Formsets` - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you have two separate HTML `<form>` elements and submit buttons. If you want both forms to be submitted and processed at the same time, they need to be within the same form element.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id = "formTv">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form_tv.as_p }}

{{ form_fridge.as_p }}
<button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
</form>
```

You might also want to use the `prefix` argument when instantiating your forms in the view, to avoid similarly-named fields from clashing.

Comment: No, I need two form, because user can see one of forms. He chooses what form they want to fill.

Comment: Nice answer I didn't knew this about prefix.

Answer (score 0):

You should add a hidden field, to distinguish which form was submitted.

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id = "formTv">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form_tv.as_p }}
    <input type="hidden" id="form_type" name="form_type" value="form_tv">
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>

    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id = "formFridge">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form_fridge.as_p }}
    <input type="hidden" id="form_type" name="form_type" value="form_fridge">
    <button type="submit" class="save btn btn-default">Save</button>
    </form>
```

So when one of the forms is submitted, you can find which form was submitted.

```
#views.py
def add_new(request):
    if request.method == "POST":  #check if the request is POST call or not.
        form_type = request.POST.get("form_type")
        form = None
        # check which form to evaluate
        if form_type == "form_fridge":
            form = FridgeForm(request.POST, request.FILES, use_required_attribute=False)

        if form_type == "form_tv":
            form = TvForm(request.POST, request.FILES, use_required_attribute=False)

        # evaluate the form
        if form and form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('new')

    return render(request, 'appliances/add_new.html', {'form_tv': form_tv,
                                                       'form_fridge': form_fridge})
```

Answer (score -1):

Let's say you have tose 2 forms:

```py
class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    title = forms.CharField(max_length=150)
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=200, widget=forms.TextInput)


class SubscriptionForm(forms.Form):
    email = forms.EmailField()
```

The Django FormView is the staple class for handling forms this way.
At the minimum, it needs:

A form_class attribute that points to the class whose form we
want to process.

A success_url attribute to indicate which URL to redirect to upon
successful form processing.

A form_valid method to do the actual processing logic.

So in your views:

```py
class MultipleFormsDemoView(MultiFormsView):
    template_name = "pages/cbv_multiple_forms.html"
    form_classes = {'contact': ContactForm,
                    'subscription': SubscriptionForm,
                    }

    success_urls = {
        'contact': reverse_lazy('contact-form-redirect'),
        'subscription': reverse_lazy('submission-form-redirect'),
    }

    def contact_form_valid(self, form):
        'contact form processing goes in here'

    def subscription_form_valid(self, form):
        'subscription form processing goes in here'
```

On your template:

```html
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ forms.subscription }}
    <input type="submit" value="Subscribe">
</form>
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ forms.contact }}
    <input type="submit" value="Send">
</form>
```

[You might also want to check inline forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/modelforms/#inline-formsets)