# Multiple Views from a single form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a django app in which there are forms which allow user to enter their data. 
When I run the app it shows the entry fields vertically like this:

[image]

here is the Forms.py

```
class SupplierTruckForm(forms.ModelForm):
    supplier_type = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    subject = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    supplier_address = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'id': 'pac-input','class': 'controls'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Supplier
        fields = (
        'supplier_name','supplier_address', 'supplier_company_name', 'supplier_email', 'supplier_gst',
        'supplier_origin_city', 'supplier_pan', 'supplier_service','subject', 'supplier_type')

        widgets = {'subject': forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple,'supplier_type':forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple}
```

Can I convert my page into something like this(below) without splitting my form into smaller forms ?
I believe two forms are used here in a template.

[image]

Comment: you can use single form to do this. You have to do some styling in css to achieve this.

Comment: Can you show me some example or refer any link ?

Comment: If your using bootstrap refer this : [link](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/3XrGb)

Comment: Do you want two forms on a single page? checkout https://stackoverflow.com/a/55684118/4186008

Comment: @SureshKumar The link you jut sent is for pure HTML

Comment: @RahulSharma Yes. As in the shared link you have to write `{{form.fieldname}}` in the place of `input` elements